# "had they known" or "if they had known"

Tags: difference, sentence-construction

Can this:

> These same officials, however, would have been appalled **had they known** what was going on behind this façade of self-help.

be rephrased as

> These same officials, however, would have been appalled **if they had known** what was going on behind this façade of self-help.

?

Comment: I think in second phrase "if" can mean "whether". This may be ambiguous. Am I correct?

Comment: There's no ambiguity. The "whether" interpretation of *if* doesn't arise when the clause expresses a condition, only if the clause is the subject of some question or uncertainty: *I'm not sure **if** they knew what was going on*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rephrasing is fine, however, the first leans towards the formal stylistically.

In general, the hypothetical if clauses (if + were/had) can be replaced with the construction "had/were (subject)."

For example:

"If I had known, I would have acted sooner" -> "Had I known, I would have acted sooner"
"If he were taller, he could reach the ceiling" -> "Were he taller, he could reach the ceiling"

There are stylistic issues that make some replacements sound awkward and stiff.