# "Had they not intervened" OR "If they had not intervened"

Tags: grammar

Could someone please explain the grammar used in the text below?

> Officers are convinced the bloodshed at the Christian school would
>   have been worse **had Meis and the others not intervened.**
>
> <sub>Source: [CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2014/06/06/us/seattle-hero-profile/)</sub>

According to what I have learned so far it should be :

> Officers are convinced the bloodshed at the Christian school would
>   have been worse **if Meis and the others had not intervened.**

Comment: Check this out: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/9363/3281.

Comment: @DamkerngT. As always, Thank you so much :) So it is written in formal style. We don't use it in colloquial speech.